# iOS9 FBSDKShareDialog native sharing not completes a post to facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, swift3, ios9, fbsdksharedialog

I have an app written in Swift3 for iOS9 which attempts to share a custom link with image and description to facebook. The inter-app switching Plist keys are configured correctly - the user is asked for permission to open facebook, then a native facebook post is created in FB app.

The issue is that **upon tapping Post, the user is returned to my app, but the FB post does not complete.** I see a little black screen with a progress indicator flash, but the user is returned to my app before the progress is filled. (Same progress indicator fills up when using "automatic" share mode within the app)

**How to make sure that FBSDKShareDialog completes posting a link to facebook native app before returning to my app?**

```
    let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
    content.contentURL = URL(string: "http://customurl.com/")
    content.contentTitle = "Custom Title"
    content.contentDescription = "Custom description"

    if let imageUrlUnwrapped = imageUrl {
        content.imageURL = URL(string: imageUrlUnwrapped)
    }

    let dialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
    dialog.fromViewController = self;
    dialog.shareContent = content;

    let url = URL(string: "fbauth2://")
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!)
    {
        dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.native
    }
    dialog.show()
```